# partial sum of $\sum^h_{i=1}\sum^i_{j=1}ij$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I am trying to come up with a fast partial sum for a big series in a program that I am writing in order to simplify some loops. However there is an internal sum inside that to me should be able to be simplified. What would be the partial sum of this be:
$$\sum^h_{i=1}\sum^i_{j=1}ij$$

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i = 1}^h \sum_{j = 1}^i ij
&= \sum_{i = 1}^h i \sum_{j=1}^i j\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^h i \left ( \frac{i(i+1)}{2} \right )\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^h i^3 + i^2\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left ( \frac{h^2 (h+1)^2}{4} + \frac{h(h+1)(2h+1)}{6} \right )
\end{align*}
$$

Of course, you can keep simplifying from here.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you! You are so fast that I have to wait to accept your answer lol.

Comment: haha, no worries. Happy to help ^_^

Answer (score 3):

First note that

$$
\begin{align}
\left(\sum^h_{i=1}i\right)^2 &= \left(\sum^h_{i=1}i\right) \left(\sum^h_{j=1}j \right) \\
&= \sum^h_{i=1}\sum^h_{j=1}ij \\
&= \sum^h_{i=1}\sum^i_{j=1}ij + \sum^h_{i=1}\sum^h_{j=i}ij \\
&= 2 \sum^h_{i=1}\sum^i_{j=1}ij - \sum^h_{i=1}i^2.\tag1
\end{align}
$$

On the other hand (see [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression))

$$
\sum^h_{i=1}i = \frac{h(h+1)}{2}
$$

and (see [square pyramidal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number))

$$
\sum^h_{i=1}i^2 = \frac{h(h+1)(2h+1)}{6}.
$$

Substituting into $(1)$

$$
\sum^h_{i=1}\sum^i_{j=1}ij = \frac{h^2(h+1)^2}{8} + \frac{h(h+1)(2h+1)}{12}.
$$