# Closed form coefficients of Elementary Symmetric Polynomial specialized to the natural numbers

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

I am writing a program that computes a [Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) using parallel processing for data points situated at every natural number. But I can have $n$ many data points, which will potentially create a polynomial of degree $n$. Doing some math and research I found out that what I need is a general form for the $ith$ coefficient of the [Elementary Symmetric Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) specialized to the natural numbers. I just asked a question about about a double sum inside one of the solving for one of the coefficients [partial sum of $\sum^h_{i=1}\sum^i_{j=1}ij$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3968567/partial-sum-of-sumh-i-1-sumi-j-1ij). But I thought I would ask the whole thing here.

To give some examples the coefficients of the cubic case would be $x^3-(1+2+3)x^2+(1*2+2*3+1*3)x-1*2*3$ and the quartic case would be $x^4-(1+2+3+4)x^3+(1*2+2*3+1*3+1*4+2*4+3*4)x^2-(1*2*3+1*3*4+1*2*4+2*3*4)x-1*2*3*4$

Because the polynomials would be like $(x-3)(x-2)(x-1)$ as an example.

I spent all morning coming up with only the first three partial sums of for the coefficients.

Which are $1,\frac{n(n+1)}{2},\frac{(n-1)n(n+1)(3n+2)}{24},\frac{n^2(n+1)^2(n-1)(n-2)}{48}$. Before I embark on trying to get the next coefficient then trying to generalize from there, is there a solution (I am not an expert in what seems to be combinatoric algebra) that someone can point me too for the closed form for each of the coefficients or a proof that someone can show.

I read [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167794/examples-of-specializations-of-elementary-symmetric-polynomials) but this is a little over my head meaning that I don't know if my answer is in there or not. I am computer guy, so any simplified explanation is greatly appreciated.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Edit: I did more research and I am came across [Vieta's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), maybe I can use this for a closed form.

Edit 2: I found this post talking about Stirling numbers [Coefficients of polynomial $(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3291332/coefficients-of-polynomial-x1x2-xn?noredirect=1&lq=1) I am wondering if I can manipulate it to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after a while. The coefficients are calculated using the signed Stirling numbers of the first kind.

These are the signed stirling numbers of the first kind
[image]

In order to get the coefficients you select the row by the degree of the polynomial and read it from right to left.

To calculate it, the facts I used were

$$s(n,k)=-(n-1)\cdot s(n-1,k)+s(n-1,k-1)$$
$$s(n,n) = 1$$
$$s(n,0) = 0, n >0$$

And what is interesting is the polynomials that I found
$1,\frac{n(n+1)}{2},\frac{(n-1)n(n+1)(3n+2)}{24},\frac{n^2(n+1)^2(n-1)(n-2)}{48}$
describe the diagonals.

So for instance $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is the diagonal 0,1,3,6,10,15,... (at positions (2,1),(3,2),(4,3),...)

And another example would be for $\frac{(n-1)n(n+1)(3n+2)}{24}$ where the value on the diagonal are 2,11,35,...

So a future follow up question would be is there a closed form for the diagonals of the stirling numbers of the first kind?